# Actual comments not showing, but form is?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I have edited the comments form to remove a few fields and now the approved comments don't show up, just the form itself.

What am I missing from this?

```
<?php
$comment_args = array(
    'fields' => apply_filters(
        'comment_form_default_fields', array(
            'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
                '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name_' ) . '</label> ' .
                ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' .
                esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />' .
                '</p><!-- #form-section-author .form-section -->',
            'url'    => ''
        )
    ),
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment">' .
        '<label for="comment">' . __( '' ) . '</label>' .
        '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .
        '</p><!-- #form-section-comment .form-section -->',
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'title_reply' => 'Leave a Comment',
     'comment_notes_before' => '',
);
comment_form( $comment_args );
?>
```

No sign of the commentslist? Even adding wp_list_comments doesn’t work.

Anyone able to help, many thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You could try  [`get_comments();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments#Usage) 
Add it right underneath `comment_form($comment_args);`

Comment: No that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Your format looks a bit off to me.  I'd try it more like this:

```
<?php $fields = array(
                      'author' => '<p><label for="author"><span class="req">* </span>' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
                      'email'  => '<p><label for="email"><span class="req">* </span>' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
                      'url'    => '',
                     );
      $theme_defaults = array(
                              'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment">' . '<label for="comment">' . __( '' ) . '</label>' . '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' . '</p><!-- #form-section-comment .form-section -->',
                              'comment_notes_after' => '',
                              'title_reply' => 'Leave a Comment',
                              'comment_notes_before' => '',
                             );

comment_form( $comment_args ); ?>
```

Source: [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

Comment: Thanks Shelly but that doesnt work either :( No comments list.

Comment: Are you only showing us *part* of your file?  I'm thinking maybe the issue is elsewhere then.  I know for a fact the above works (with commentlist) after it) because it's my default for most of the sites I create.  Have you checked your error logs to see if there's an error co,ing up that you aren't seeing?